# Why does RAD Studio CreateBlobStream with CryptUnprotectData return extra characters?

Tags: c++, winapi, c++builder

I'm writing a recovery app that pulls passwords from Chrome.  It has a GUI, so I've used their SQLite wrapper, which uses both SQLConnection and SQLQuery. Here's a snip of my code:

```
//Create our blob stream
TStream *Stream2 = SQLQuery1->CreateBlobStream(SQLQuery1->FieldByName("password_value"), bmRead);
//Get our blob size
int size = Stream2->Size;
//Create our buffer
char* pbDataInput = new char[size+1];
//Adding null terminator to buffer
memset(pbDataInput, 0x00, sizeof(char)*(size+1));
//Write to our buffer
Stream2->ReadBuffer(pbDataInput, size);
DWORD cbDataInput = size;

DataOut.pbData = pbDataInput;
DataOut.cbData = cbDataInput;

LPWSTR pDescrOut = NULL;
//Decrypt password
CryptUnprotectData( &DataOut,
        &pDescrOut,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        0,
        &DataVerify);

//Output password
UnicodeString password = (UnicodeString)(char*)DataVerify.pbData;
passwordgrid->Cells[2][i] = password;
```

The output data looks fine, except it behaves as if something went wrong with my null terminator. Here's what output looks like on every line:

[image: Output Data With Extra Chars at end of Password]

**I've Read**

Windows doc for `CryptUnprotectData`:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa382377.aspx

Embarcadero documentation for `CreateBlobStream`:

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Data.DB.TDataSet.CreateBlobStream

memset:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memset/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reading and decrypting calls operate on raw bytes only, they know nothing about strings, and don't care about them.  The null-terminator you are adding to `pbDataInput` is never used, so get rid of it:

```
//Get our blob size
int size = Stream2->Size;
//Create our buffer
char* pbDataInput = new char[size];
//Write to our buffer
Stream2->ReadBuffer(pbDataInput, size);
DWORD cbDataInput = size;
...
delete[] pbDataInput;
delete Stream2;
```

Now, when assigning `pbData` to `password`, you are casting `pbData` to `char*`, so the `UnicodeString` constructor interprets the data as a null-terminated ANSI string and will convert it to UTF-16 using the system default ANSI codepage, which is potentially a lossy conversion for non-ASCII characters. Is that what you really want?

If so, and if the decrypted data is not actually null-terminated, you have to specify the number of characters to the `UnicodeString` constructor:

```
UnicodeString password( (char*)DataVerify.pbData, DataVerify.cbData );
```

On the other hand, if the decrypted output is already in UTF-16, you need to cast `pbData` to `wchar_t*` instead:

```
UnicodeString password = (wchar_t*)DataVerify.pbData;
```

Or, if not null-terminated:

```
UnicodeString password( (wchar_t*)DataVerify.pbData, DataVerify.cbData / sizeof(wchar_t) );
```

Comment: Thank you, I got it in my head it had something to do with the null terminator. Upvoting your answer.